# importing data from excel to SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, excel-2003, import-from-excel

I have the following problem
1-i have a database with a table called prod and 3 attributes Codep varchar (15) Namep varchar (40) and DateR datetime 
2- I have a excel file with a sheet called prod and 3 columns with the same names of table columns(the first row have the columns names ) I have some info like 50 rows...
3 - when I try to import the excel data to SQL server 2008 it try to create a new table with the name prod$ I don't want that. I want import the data to my existing table prod no create a new one

What should I do to SQL import wizard recognize my excel sheet and insert the  data into my table ?

Comment: Don't use the wizard. Use BIDS (Business Intelligence Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the wizard lets you choose the destination, just click on the drop down

[image]

Comment: Thanks lookslikeanevo that is what a needed... Thanks all u guys. I need reach 15 points to + your answers..

Answer (score 0):

**Tutorial with screenshots**

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

**Query:**

SELECT * INTO XLImport3 FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\test\xltest.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Customers$]